# Make lines disappear, pst-solides3D

Tags: pstricks, 3d, transparency, pst-solides3d

I'm drawing the following cylinder which represents a water flowing and cooling down

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %change language if necessary
\usepackage[english,verbose]{layout}%change language if necessary

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=50 50 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint 
} 
 \psset{color1=cyan,color2=red} 
 \psSolid[h=8,r=0.5, object=cylindre, ngrid=50 15, RotZ=30,
hue =1 0 0 0 0 1,linewidth=0.01pt ](0,0,-2.5)  \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like the black lines to disappear, or atleast partially merge with the image. Is there anyway to perform this ?

Comment: Did you try to use 0pt for the line width?

Comment: Yes, it makes white lines which are not really pretty. I have found a way though. Set linewidth = 0pt and plot a second cylinder on top of the first with a slightly different ngrid.

Comment: @Mathusalem: `linewidth=0pt` is not the correct way. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use option `grid`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-4)(3,4) 
\psset{viewpoint=50 50 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint,
  color1=cyan,color2=red} 
\psSolid[h=8,r=0.5, object=cylindre, ngrid=50 15, RotZ=30,
  hue =1 0 0 0 0 1,grid=false](0,0,-2.5)  
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that this does not work when the option `opacity` is used for transparency.

Comment: `action=draw*`   should help

Comment: actually mixing `action=draw*` with `grid=false` makes the strangest behavior: only hidden grid lines are shown (but dashed).